# Can a firmware upgrade enable a Nikon D90 to use SDXC memory cards?

Tags: nikon-d90, firmware, firmware-hacks, sdxc

I have a Nikon D90 and today found out that my SDXC card prohibits me from recording Video (the `REC` shows up on the monitor with a diagonal slash running through it), although, still pictures work fine.

I see that Nikon has a [firmware update V101M available here](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/9.html), but there are no release notes that I can find to see what is fixed in any of their firmmare releases.  I'd like to know whether the SDXC issue has been fixed in any of their firmware revisions before installed an updated firmware.  The only thing listed for the latest firmware update is:

> Support for distortion control data Ver. L: 2.000

But I don't know what that means, what is distortion control data?  Regardless, how can I find the release notes for prior firmware versions to see if any of them mention SDXC support being added?

Bottom line, does the latest firmware support SDXC cards for video recording on the Nikon D90?  Alternatively, has anybody hacked it to add support?

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't installed the update and tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, a firmware update *could* improve SDXC compatibility to support video. However, based on historical precedence, it's unlikely to happen. No such update appears to exist as of Sep 2018. See [Nikon D90 SDXC Compatibility](https://photographylife.com/nikon-d90-sdxc-compatibility).